# Failing to create Cocoapod private podspecs repo off iOS wrapper framework of a React Native (0.71.3) app

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am currently attempting to create a Cocoapod of an iOS wrapper framework which allows my React Native (0.71.3) app to be distributed to 3rd party subscribers. The framework has to act as a bridge to start my React Native application on trigger sent from the subscriber app.

Due to my limited understanding of the behaviour and usage of Cocoapods, I was facing a number of issues. This is one where I cannot find a way around.

The Podfile for my iOS Cocoapod is as below --

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'BareSdk' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'BareSdkTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

My iOS Cocoapod Podspec is --

```
react_native_version = "0.71.3"

current_file_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "My-SDK-POC"
  s.version      = "1.0"
  s.summary      = "My-SDK-POC"
  s.description  = "My-SDK-POC react native SDK"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/VKMDGOAT"
  
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "John Smith" => "jsmith@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "14.0"
  s.source       =  { :git => 'https://github.com/org/my-sdk-poc.git' }
  s.source_files = "ios-sdk-poc/**/*.{swift,h,m,mm,cpp}"
  s.preserve_paths = "ios-sdk-poc/**/*"

  s.requires_arc = true
  s.swift_version= '5.0'

  Dir.each_child(File.join(current_file_dir, 'Pods/Local Podspecs')) do |podspec_name|
    podspec_split_name = podspec_name.split(/\./)
    s.dependency podspec_split_name[0]
  end
end
```

When running `pod repo push ios-podspecs My-SDK-POC.podspec`, to create and push the dependency podspecs to my private repository, I am seeing the following error --

```
Testing with `xcodebuild`.
-> My-SDK-POC (1.0)
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
...
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Headers/Public/hermes-engine/jsi/jsi.h:10:10: fatal error: 'cassert' file not found
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  React-RCTText/Libraries/Text/VirtualText/RCTVirtualTextViewManager.m:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'React'
[!] The `My-SDK-POC.podspec` specification does not validate.
```

I am also seeing multiple warnings of the form --

```
[!] Found multiple specifications for `glog (0.3.4)`:
- /Users/johnSmith/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/4/7/2/glog/0.3.4/glog.podspec.json
- /Users/johnSmith/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/4/7/2/glog/0.3.4/glog.podspec.json

[!] Found multiple specifications for `React (0.13.0-rc)`:
- /Users/johnSmith/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/5/0/c/React/0.13.0-rc/React.podspec.json
- /Users/johnSmith/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/5/0/c/React/0.13.0-rc/React.podspec.json
...
```

I tried =>

1. Listing all the Pods individually as dependencies in the Podspec
2. Changing the C/C++ Language dialects in Xcode
   but to no avail